# Why are appended vectors throwing away data?

Tags: c++

I have a number of vectors contained inside one large vector with pointers. Now I'd like to merge vectors in this list based on an arbitrary condition. This involves first appending the two vectors together, then removing one of them from the "large" vector.

When I run the program, I occasionally get a case where a vector of length 6 and 12 are merged together, giving a total length of 12 (thus throwing away 6 elements).

I've tried to recreate the problem in one contained C++ file. I didn't quite manage this (this one throws a non-debuggable index out of bounds error). As far as I can tell I'm messing up a number of things here.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int>*> lists;

    //create lists with variable size
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        std::vector<int> vec;
        for(int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            vec.push_back(j);
        }
        lists.push_back(&vec);
    }

    //do the merging
    bool changed = true;
    while(changed) {
        changed = false;
        for(int list = 0; list < (int)lists.size(); list++) {
            std::vector<int>* listInstance = lists.at(list);
            for(int otherList = 0; otherList < (int)lists.size(); otherList++) {
                if(list == otherList) {//avoid merging lists with themselves
                    continue;
                }
                std::vector<int>* otherListInstance = lists.at(otherList);

                if(lists.at(otherList)->size() % 4 == 0) { //some arbitrary condition for merging.
                    changed = true;

                    int otherSize = otherListInstance->size();

                    listInstance->insert(listInstance->end(), otherListInstance->begin(), otherListInstance->end());
                    lists.erase(lists.begin() + otherList);

                    if(otherSize != otherListInstance->size()) {
                        std::cout << "Does not match!\n";
                    }

                    otherList--;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are pushing pointers to a temporary. `vec` is destroyed at the end of each outer loop, right after you call `push_back`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are pushing pointers to local variables. That's undefined behavior.

Change

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>*> lists;

//create lists with variable size
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    std::vector<int> vec;
    for(int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        vec.push_back(j);
    }
    lists.push_back(&vec);
}
```

to

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> lists;

//create lists with variable size
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    std::vector<int> vec;
    for(int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        vec.push_back(j);
    }
    lists.push_back(vec);
}
```

Or create a non-local version using `new`.

```
std::vector<std::vector<int> *> lists;

//create lists with variable size
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    std::vector<int> * vec = new std::vector<int>();
    for(int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        vec->push_back(j);
    }
    lists.push_back(vec);
}
```

Of course it is better to use an `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<std::vector<int> > >` as your type for lists. That way, you do not need to do manual memory management.

Comment: I think using <auto_ptr> or boost::tr1::shared_ptr<> will also work. C++11 will be unique_ptr<>?

Comment: @hagubear Don't use `auto_ptr`. It cannot handle copies properly. Use the `shared_ptr` of `boost` or `std::tr1`. A unique pointer cannot be copied, (but it can be moved); in `C++11`, you can use `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: Getting rid of the pointers and keeping everything on the stack did indeed the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Pushing pointers to local variables yields undefined behavior if those variables go out-of-scope:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    std::vector<int> vec;
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        vec.push_back(j);
    }
    lists.push_back(&vec); // Pointer to an in-scope local variable
}

// Now lists contains pointers to invalid stack areas
```

Since it seems you're just trying to create a vector of int vectors, you could simply store it without pointers:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> lists;

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    std::vector<int> vec;
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        vec.push_back(j);
    }
    lists.push_back(vec);
}
```

with that change (and obviously also changing every dereferencing to a member-access), e.g.

```
lists.at(otherList)->size() ---> lists.at(otherList).size()
```

your code will do just fine.

If you really need/want to use pointers, make sure to allocate them on the heap and I'd also suggest using a [smart pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer#C.2B.2B_smart_pointers) to store it.

Comment: I used the int vectors as an example. They are struct vectors in my program. Would I in that case need to use pointers?

Comment: It would be the same in that case. The problem is with storing pointers to the local stack vectors (i.e. they will get reused/destroyed when the scope of the for loop exits or when the loop restarts). If the structures aren't very heavy-weight you might go as I wrote above. If they're heavy-weight you'd better move pointers to heap memory (allocated with 'new')